# How do I normalize an image in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to **normalize** each of my input images by a **mean** and **standard deviation** of **0.5**.

Each image is represented as a float between 0 and 1 with three channels (RGB).

I understand that the PyTorch equivalent of what I'm trying to do is:

```
torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5,0.5,0.5])
```

How can this be achieved in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not know specfics of using tensorflow methods, but to do it
in python you can use the code below

```
def fit_data(x, mean, sd):
    # x is the input array, mean is the desired mean, sd is the desired standard deviation
    import numpy as np
    import math
    shape=x.shape
    x= x.flatten ()
    y=np.zeros((x.shape[0]))
    total=0
    for i in x:
        total += i
    x_mean=total/x.shape[0]    
    s_sq=0
    for i in x:
        s_sq +=(i-x_mean)**2     
    s=math.sqrt(s_sq/x.shape[0])        
    for i,v in enumerate(x):
        y[i]=mean + (v-x_mean)*sd/s
    y=np.reshape(y, shape)    
    return y
```